# BlockingCollection + UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, concurrency

I've followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460690.aspx), to create a priority queue and wrapped it with a blocking collection. I've got a DataGrid which I've wired to the underlying priority queue which emits change events. I can add items to the collection from the UI thread w/out a hitch, and it blocks when the buffer is full as it's supposed to.

Now how do I consume the items? Here's what I've got:

```
public DownloadViewModel()
{
    Queue = new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<DownloadItem>(10);
    Buffer = new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<int, DownloadItem>>(Queue, 10000);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        KeyValuePair<int, DownloadItem> item;
        while(!Buffer.IsCompleted)
        {
            if(Buffer.TryTake(out item))
            {
                // do something with the item
            }

            Thread.SpinWait(100000);
        }
    });
}
```

But as soon as I added that `Task.Factory.StartNew` bit, my app suddenly takes 30 seconds before the window appears (before it was instant), and when I do add an item I get the exception

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Which I understand, but is it really necessary to take the items using the UI thread? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of using this BlockingCollection? I want to create 4 or 8 consumers and have them run in parallel.

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: It is *really* necessary to only ever update a UI control from the UI thread.  Which is what the exception is telling you.  Yes, this quickly defeats the usefulness of elaborate threading schemes.

Comment: @Hans: Sure, but when the blocking queue tries to take an item, the underlying queue emits a change notification, .. why can't that be automatically delegated back to the UI thread? Why should the consumers be held up? Regardless.. I'm willing to accept any sol'n right now, even if it's a little less efficient than I think it ought to be. I'd imagine this is a pretty common paradigm.. producer-consumer is nothing new, it shouldn't be that difficult to display the remaining items to the user?

Comment: Nothing is ever automatic or easy when it comes to threading.  Collect the results in a list and use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to update the UI.

Comment: The consumers shouldn't be held up... the consumers should consume the items, and do whatever they do (download an item?) and any changes the consumption of those items causes to the UI should be dispatched to the UI from the consumer.  It would be a bit silly to both produce and consume on the UI thread - it'd defeat the whole purpose of multi-threading, surely?  (No time to follow the article or produce a working example, so not a full answer for you I'm afraid)

Comment: @Giraffe: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to say. The consumers shouldn't be bottle-necked because they're waiting to update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the `CollectionChanged` event w/ a dispatcher seems work pretty well...

```
public bool TryAdd(KeyValuePair<int, T> item)
{
    int pos = _queues.Take(item.Key + 1).Sum(q => q.Count);
    _queues[item.Key].Enqueue(item.Value);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        new Action(
            () =>
            NotifyCollectionChanged(
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, pos))
        ));
    return true;
}
```

Just had to derive my `ConcurrentPriorityQueue` from `DispatcherObject`. I *think* this is how it's supposed to be done.

---

Easier yet, just write the `NotifyCollectionChanged` method like this:

```
private void NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (CollectionChanged)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CollectionChanged(this, e)));
    }
}
```

And then you don't have to litter your other methods with `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Could you possibly post a code sample (of MainWindow.xaml.cs)?

Comment: @Fulproof: Couldn't find a sample that uses this class, but here's the full class: http://goo.gl/9BWb7

Comment: thanks, but the class code you proviced  gives compilation error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'"

Comment: @Fulproof: Weird...I wonder if there were some changes made to the threading API since I wrote that? This is over 2 years old now ;) Or maybe it plain old doesn't work, I don't know. Haven't touched that project in just as long.

Answer (score 1):

[After commenting on the question, then]

You don't need to "take the items using the UI thread".  However, any updates to the UI as a result of processing the item in the consuming task need to be dispatched to the UI thread.  Separate your concerns!